# Ruby on Rails: custom rendering in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So basically I have this for my index page:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
end
```

I implemented soft deletion, which basically works like this: there is an additional boolean column in db that is called is_active and is true by default. Deleting is rewritten to just change that to false instead of destruction, and made a page to view soft-deleted entries.

The issue: current workaround I found for paginate is to simply add

```
<% if article.is_active %>
```

in my index.html.erb. The flaw is: when I delete something it still considered there by paginate, so instead of say 15 entries I will see 14. Even worse, on undeleting page it shows same amount of blank pages, and deleted entries are on their would-be-appropriate pages (so for example first entry may end up being on page 14 instead of 1). It is not critical flaw, but I'd like to know if I can fix it without rewriting too much.

Maybe I can change something in controller so it doesn't send any entries that have true or false in that field depending on what I want to output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just filter by this field?

```
@articles = Article.where(is_active: true).paginate(per_page: 15, page: params[:page])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! I'm just getting hang of ruby on rails, but not completely new to programming, so I suspected there is more than just .all or .paginate, etc., just wasn't sure how to google it properly.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html This guide is the best place to start, good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scope or a where clause to get only active articles:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.where("is_active = ?", true).paginate(:per_page => 15, :page => params[:page])
end
```